# How to use F# records or discriminated unions in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, f#, record, discriminated-union

I created a F# project by running these commands:

```
dotnet new sln -o DotnetCoreProj
cd DotnetCoreProj
dotnet new classlib -lang 'F#' -o src/MyFSModule
dotnet sln add src/MyFSModule/MyFSModule.fsproj
cd src/MyFSModule
@'
namespace MyFSModule
module jwt = 
    type jwtHeader = {
      typ: string
      alg: string
    }

    type hsAlgorithm = HS256 | HS384 | HS512
'@ | Out-File Library.fs -Encoding UTF8
dotnet build
dotnet publish
Import-Module ./bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/MyFSModule.dll
```

Even though I import the module, I am unable to use the types.

```
PS> $test = [MyFSModule]
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [MyFSModule].
PS> $test = [MyFSModule]::new()
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [MyFSModule].
PS> $test = [jwt]              
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [jwt].
PS> $test = [jwt]::new()
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [jwt].
PS> $test = [MyFSModule+jwt]::new()
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [MyFSModule+jwt].
PS> $test = [MyFSModule+jwt]       
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [MyFSModule+jwt].
PS> $test = [MyFSModule+hsAlgorithm]
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [MyFSModule+hsAlgorithm].
PS> $test = [hsAlgorithm]           
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [hsAlgorithm].
PS> $test = [jwt+hsAlgorithm]
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [jwt+hsAlgorithm].
PS> $fs = [MyFSModule.jwt]
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [MyFSModule.jwt].
```

When I run `Get-Module -Name MyFSModule`, nothing is exported either.

How do I make F# types available in PowerShell?

Comment: `MyFSModule` is not a type, but a namespace. It says so in your source code, right at the top. `jwt`, however, is a type (from .NET point of view). Try `[MyFSModule.jwt]`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, I got the same error response (added it to the question body). Is it possible to use `F#` types with PowerShell or is there some restrictions because discriminated unions or records are for example not a type available in PowerShell normally?

Comment: Are you sure the import is succeeding? When I copy/paste your commands into PowerShell, I get this error: `Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost right.

```
C:\Projects\psfspoc> [MyFSModule.jwt+jwtHeader]::new("typ","alg")

typ  alg
---  ---
typ  alg

C:\Projects\psfspoc> [MyFSModule.jwt+hsAlgorithm]::HS256

Tag IsHS256 IsHS384 IsHS512
--- ------- ------- -------
  0    True   False   False
```

It's quite nice to explore the options by start writing `[MyFSModule.jwt+` and then use ctrl-space to select the right option.

It's btw a very nice idea to use F# types from Powershell.